# how to add multiple formats to the same text with XlsxWriter

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlsxwriter

The following examples from the [docs](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/blob/master/dev/docs/source/worksheet.rst#worksheetwrite_rich_string) work great:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('rich_strings.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.set_column('A:A', 30)

# Set up some formats to use.
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
italic = workbook.add_format({'italic': True})
red = workbook.add_format({'color': 'red'})

# Write some strings with multiple formats.
worksheet.write_rich_string('A1',
                            'This is ',
                            bold, 'bold',
                            ' and this is ',
                            italic, 'italic')
```

But how would I do something ***bold and italic***?

The following does not work.

```
worksheet.write_rich_string('A1',
                            'This is ',
                            bold, 'bold',
                            ', this is ',
                            italic, 'italic',                                
                            ', and this is',
                            bold and italic, ' bold and italic')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to set up another format that is both bold and italic.

For example:

```
bold_and_italic = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'italic': True})
```

A fully Reproducible version:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('rich_strings.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.set_column('A:A', 50)

bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
italic = workbook.add_format({'italic': True})
red = workbook.add_format({'color': 'red'})
bold_and_italic = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'italic': True})


worksheet.write_rich_string('A1',
                            'This is', bold, ' bold', 
                            ' and this is ', italic, ' italic',  
                            ' and this is', bold_and_italic, ' bold and italic')

workbook.close()
```

with Expected Output:
[image: Expected Output]